# Update pkpass file remotely without an app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, passbook, applepay, wallet

I built a website to my store and added some coupons to it. I added a link to download a pkpass file with a coupon, so my clients could save their coupons to their Apple Wallet app. I would like to have to option to update that card remotely after my customers save it to their device (like change the coupon text) but everything I read about it, says that you can only update the card if the customer saved it from an app and not from web. 
Is that correct? Is there no way to push an update to my coupon if I don't have an app installed on this user's device? Is there any way around it?

Comment: Your understanding is not correct - one major benefit of Passes is that they do not need an app. You simply need to implement the web service as detailed in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have a PassKit Web Service for the pass to register itself with when it's added to the wallet:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html

Updating a Pass is explained in the Wallet Developer Guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1